# Spring banner from other sources or built at run time with gradle

Tags: spring, gradle

I'd like to embed my application version in my start up banner.  The version is managed by a gradle plugin so it lives in another file called `version.txt`, the contents being `0.1.3` or `0.1.3-SNAPSHOT`.  I know spring supports some tokens in banners, but `${application.version}` isn't showing up.

Ideally, I'd like to reference the property in that way so I can put it in the middle of the banner.

Simply appending `version.txt` is an acceptable solution at this point, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a file with my banner and `VERSION` as placeholder text then added this to `build.gradle`

```
processResources.dependsOn 'buildBanner'

task buildBanner() << {
    def BANNER_WIDTH = 79

    def banner = new File("bannerWithoutVersion.txt").text;
    def version = new File("version.txt").text.center(BANNER_WIDTH);
    banner = banner.replaceAll("VERSION", version);

    new File("src/main/resources/banner.txt").write(banner);
}
```

I did some other work to handle building from different folders, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file to your artifact with by adding a `Copy` task

```
task addFile(type: Copy) {
    from('path/to')
    include 'version.txt'
    into 'build/resources/main'
}
processResources.dependsOn 'addFile'
```

Then your task will run during the build before the `processResources` task.